# Assembler task : scalar product of two arrays

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I have a trouble with simple assembler program.I don't know what i why happens but there is problem.
Task is : Compute scalar product of two arrays in assembler (emu 8086)
Here is my code

```
    ; multi-segment executable file template.
```

data segment
    ; add your data here!
    n1 db 1,2,3
    n2 db 4,5,6
    i db ?
    j db ?

```
k dw ?
pkey db "press any key...$"
```

ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends

code segment
start:
; set segment registers:
    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

```
mov al,00h
mov ah,02h

mov ch,00h
mov cl,03h

mov bx,offset n1
ciklus:

mov dl,[bx]
;add dl,30h


mov j,0d

add j,dl
int 21h
mov al,j
mov ah,0h


inc bx
inc bx
inc bx
mov dl,[bx]
;add dl,30h

mov i,0d
add i,dl
mul i

mov k,ax


mov al,00h
mov ah,02h
int 21h



dec bx
dec bx
dec bx

inc bx



loop ciklus

lea dx, pkey
mov ah, 9
int 21h        ; output string at ds:dx

; wait for any key....    
mov ah, 1
int 21h

mov ax, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
int 21h
```

ends

end start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.

So when i run program step by step i see strange values in ax. I want 
1x4 2x5 3x6  = > 4 10 18 to save in some variable and print to screen .

If someone can help me i will be grateful.
P.S this i'm noob in assembler programming so don't be angry of my stupid question.

Comment: Are you using a debugger to see what goes wrong and when?

Comment: Yes. when i run step by step i see after operation mul i (result should go in ax) and ax is 31h * 34* = 09F4 [2548 dec] , result should be 4  (1*4=4)... i don't know where i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `ciklus:` label, you are adding 0x30 to `dl`, then adding `dl` to `j`, so `j >= 0x30` at this point. After the interrupt you set `al` to `j`, and `ah` to `0x0`, so `ax >= 0x30`. Later you add `0x30` to `dl`, then add `dl` to `i`.

So `mul i` is effectively: [dx:ax] = i * ax, which is going to be at *least* (0x30 * 0x30), i.e., `ax >= 2304, dx = 0`. Larger, depending on the contents of [bx], i, j.

After the `mul` you overwrite the `ax` register with the value: `0x200` (512), anyway, so the results are lost. In short, you need to look at saving your running `ax [ah:al]` register before clobbering it for use as the interrupt service code.

**P.S.** You might consider using the `si` and `di` registers to save working values.

Comment: i know that i need to save result from mul i somewhere but  result  from mul  is 09F4h like i said so i don't need this number... I read your answer but i cant figure why is 09F4 why not 34h ? :( i get lost... will be nice if you can and have time to correct this simple program.btw thanks for answer

Comment: @user1260255 - I've described why the registers and variables are holding the values they do, and why the `mul` yields the results you are seeing. You need a pen and paper, some reference material on what the instructions do, what registers they affect, and a step-by-step look at what the debugger is reporting, compared to what you're expecting. It's a short program, and I suspect one of the goals of the assignment is to learn how to debug.

Comment: @user1260255 - I'm not trying to be harsh, but a fragment like: `sub dl, 30h; inc bx; inc bx; inc bx; mov dl, [bx];` - why subtract from `dl`, just to reload it again? Why use `inc bx` 3 times, when `add bx, 3` would suffice? Step through and check the assumptions. What values do `i` and `j` hold on the first iteration of the loop? Shouldn't they be initialized to a known value?

Comment: inc bx inc bx inc bx i use cos  when i look program it make for me more clearly what i'm doing. In i i store number 4 so when i used mul i i multiple i*ax in ax is j. j=1. So first iteration j=1,i=4 second j=2,i=5 and last j=3,i=6... so they shouldn't be initialized  before ciklus.in ciklus they got value what need. And last  yes i don't need sub dl,30h :S

Comment: edit: ooopss sorry  i see got wrong value  after first ciklus in i and j ...probably need to reset i and j :))

Comment: @user1260255. Ok, let's go with your statement that `(j)` doesn't need to be initialized before `ciklus:`... You declare the variable: `j db ?` - so what value does it have at `start:`? Are you hoping that the assembler sets it zero or some other value? After `ciklus:`, `mov dl, [bx]` sets `dx` to the value at the address given by `bx`. Let's say this value is `(1)` as you expect - the first byte of `n1`. `add dl, 30h` adds 0x30 (48 decimal) to `dl`. So assume `dl = 49 (0x31)`, the ASCII code for `"1"`, which you want to print. `add j, dl`, then sets `j = j + dl`. `j` will **never** be (1).

Comment: I made some modification : ciklus:
    
    mov dl,[bx]
    add dl,30h
    
    
    mov j,0d
    
    add j,dl
    int 21h
    mov al,j
    mov ah,0h
    
    
    inc bx
    inc bx
    inc bx
    mov dl,[bx]
    add dl,30h
    
    mov i,0d
    add i,dl
    mul i
    
    mov k,ax
    
    
    mov al,00h
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h
    
    
    
    dec bx
    dec bx
    dec bx
    
    inc bx
 
    
    
    loop ciklus    So now j in first iteration is 31h , i 34h and now i think that values are ok in i and j  right ?

Comment: @user1260255 - you can edit the code in your original post to make things clearer. Just run & debug the program to see if it's right, but you still have 'ASCII' (+0x30) values in `ax` and `i` for `mul`...

Comment: post edited. Now work, thanks you p.s i don't think about adding 30h to dl will make problem :@ because i wanted ascii on screen .